# How to avoid overlapping of random numbers?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, arrays

On Clicking button Click Me! How to avoid overlapping of random numbers?
It will generate random numbers but there are some numbers which are overlapping how to avoid this...  , Here I am not talking about duplicacy of random numbers , I want  to avoid overlapping of random numbers....

```js
const circle = document.querySelector(".circle");
const addNumBtn = document.querySelector('#addNumBtn')


function randomValue() {
  let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50) + 1;
  return random;
}
function randomColor(){
  let r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + 1;
  let g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + 1;
  let b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + 1;
  return `rgba(${r},${g},${b})`
}
function randomSize(){
  let size = Math.floor(Math.random() * 30) + 8;
  return `${size}px`
}
function randNum() {
  let randnum = document.createElement("p");
  randnum.classList.add('numStyle')
  randnum.style.color=randomColor();
  randnum.style.fontSize=randomSize();
  randnum.textContent = randomValue();
  randnum.style.position = 'absolute'
  randnum.style.top = `${randomValue()}px`
  randnum.style.left = `${randomValue()}px`
  randnum.style.bottom = `${randomValue()}px`
  randnum.style.right = `${randomValue()}px`
  circle.append(randnum);
}


addNumBtn.addEventListener('click',randNum)
```

```css
.circle {
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}

#addNumBtn{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}

.numStyle{
  font-family:"roboto",sans-serif;
}
```

```html
//On Clicking button Click Me! I want to place all the random numbers inside the circle 
//together not one by one, at a time all numbers should be placed inside the circle by 
//clicking 
the button Click Me!
<div id="container"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
    <button id="addNumBtn">Click Me!</button>
```

Comment: How many numbers is "*all the numbers*"? What have you tried, and where did you get stuck?

Comment: 50 numbers  , I am trying to put all the numbers(50) together inside the whole circle but somehow numbers are only appearing at top left side. How to solve this error? Please Explain...

Comment: @DavidThomas ,As you have mentioned in your profile about interest towards new projects, I am facing lot of problems in my project , any help will be appreciated...(I am not talking about this question..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to loop over the random number generator for the amount of times you wish to display the created number element in the circle. You can create and return an **array** of values in `randomValue()` function, then loop over that array in `randNum()` function.

Also, I assume you want the output of the appended element to spread out over the entirety of the circle element yes? If so, you need to randomize the position of the element relative to the size of the circle, not the `randomValue` functions returned value.

### EDIT:

OP asked after posting answer: ***There are some numbers at circles border side which are not properly visible how to solve that?***

Because of the box model of elements, the border of the circle element is square, not round though the viewable content of the circle element is round due to its **border-radius** css.

You can use a helper function that will determine if the randomly generated numbers for **x** and **y**, or **left** and **top**, are within the `border-radius` of the circle element using the *size* of the **radius** and the *center point* of the **x** and **y** ***coords*** of the circle.

**Credit for helper function:** [***Simon Sarris***](https://stackoverflow.com/users/154112/simon-sarris):

```
function pointInCircle(x, y, cx, cy, rad) {
  const distancesquared = (x - cx) * (x - cx) + (y - cy) * (y - cy);
  return distancesquared <= rad * rad;
}
```

We wrap everything inside a while loop that checks if a counter has reached 50. Inside the loop we run the function that creates the randomly generated positions -> `randomPos()`. Then we run a conditional that will check to see if the randomly generated points are within the circle using the function `pointInCircle(x, y, cx, cy, rad)`. If this conditional returns true we create the number elements, style and append the number elements to the circle and iterate our counter value by one.

```js
const circle = document.querySelector(".circle");
const addNumBtn = document.querySelector('#addNumBtn');
// we set the width of the circle element in JS and pass
// it to CSS using a css variable and the root element
const circleWidth = 350;
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--circleWidth', `${circleWidth}px`);

// NOTE: '~~' -> is quicker form of writing Math.floor() 
// runs faster on most browsers.

function randomPos(min, max) {
  return ~~(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min)
}

// return a random value between 1 and 50
function randomValue(){
  return ~~(Math.random() * 50) + 1;
}

function randomColor() {
  let r = ~~(Math.random() * 255) + 1;
  let g = ~~(Math.random() * 255) + 1;
  let b = ~~(Math.random() * 255) + 1;
  return `rgba(${r},${g},${b})`
}

function randomSize() {
  let size = ~~(Math.random() * 30) + 8;
  return `${size}px`
}

// add a helper function to find the center of the 
// circle and calculate distance to the edge of circle
// x and y are the randomly generated points
// cx, cy are center of circle x and y repsectively
// rad is circle radius
function pointInCircle(x, y, cx, cy, rad) {
  const distancesquared = (x - cx) * (x - cx) + (y - cy) * (y - cy);
  return distancesquared <= rad * rad;
}

// you can remove valArray array if you do not want the 50 numbers to not be repeated
const valArray = [];

function randNum() {
  // add a counter
  let count = 1;
  // while loop to check if the counter has reached the target 50
  while (count <= 50) {
    // set the randomly generated val
    let val = randomValue();
    // random size = string with px added
    let randSize = randomSize();
    // random size = the exact number => typeof number 
    let posSize = randSize.split('px')[0];
    // an array to hold our randomly positioned number values
    // uses helper function randonPos
    // pass in the 1 and the circle width minus the font size
    let ran = [randomPos(1, circleWidth - posSize), randomPos(1, circleWidth - posSize)];
    // conditional to check bounds of circle using helper function
    // we pass in the ran array, center points and radius
    // we add buffers to accommodate for the font size
    // you can remove !valArray.includes(val) if you do not want the 50 numbers to not be repeated
    if (pointInCircle(ran[0], ran[1], circleWidth/2-posSize, circleWidth/2-posSize, circleWidth / 2 - posSize) && !valArray.includes(val)) {
      // you can remove valArray.push(val); if you do not want the 50 numbers to not be repeated
      valArray.push(val);
      // if the conditional returns true, 
      // create the element, style and append
      let randnum = document.createElement("p");
      randnum.classList.add('numStyle');
      randnum.style.color = randomColor();
      randnum.style.fontSize = randSize;
      randnum.textContent = val;
      randnum.style.position = 'absolute';
      randnum.style.top = `${ran[0]}px`;
      randnum.style.left = `${ran[1]}px`;
      circle.append(randnum);
      // iterate the counter
      count++;
    }
  }
}

addNumBtn.addEventListener('click', randNum)
```

```css
html {
  --circle-width: 300px;
}

.circle {  
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  width: var(--circleWidth);
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: .5rem;
}


#addNumBtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.numStyle {
  font-family: "roboto", sans-serif;
}
```

```html
//On Clicking button Click Me! I want to place all the random numbers inside the circle //together not one by one, at a time all numbers should be placed inside the circle by //clicking the button Click Me!
<div id="container"></div>
<div class="circle">
</div>
<button id="addNumBtn">Click Me!</button>
```

Comment: YES Exactly What I am Looking for... Thank You so much.. One more thing, There are some numbers at circles border side which are not properly visible how to solve that??

Comment: So the element you are posting to has a `border-radius` of 50% of 300px, that is 150px. Some of the left/right/top/bottom are being created within the section of the element that is outside the border-radius, so if you have a number element with a top position of 50 and a left position of 35 then it will place that element outside of the border radius. You need logic to check those placements and then correct them to be placed in the viewable section of that elements border-radius.

Comment: Okay.., Actually I am trying to make a game in which user has to find the number in sequence out of this random numbers inside the circle Any advice to make it interactive...

Comment: Well first you need to figure out how to show the elements within the viewable section of your circle element. This will take further logic in terms of creating a 'no-go' zone that would consist of the sections of the element that are outside of the elements border-radius or if having a circle is not important, remove the border-radius. I think a different question is in order here. As for how to make it interactive, you could query the created elements classes `numStyle` and add a click event to those elements that would handle your interactivity for the use when they click on it.

Comment: @tpler got the border-radius figured out with a bit of tweaking to the code by adding a function that checks the boundaries of the radius using the generated points and center of circle with the radius, see my further edit and explanation.

Comment: How to avoid overlapping of random numbers?

Comment: Please Answer This Last Question (How to avoid overlapping of random numbers?)

Comment: You can add an array that saves the randomPos() x/y coords and the random size, which could be used as your buffer, with each iteration. Then a conditional that checks the position of each newly created randomPos() with that within the array to see if you have a clash.